How to access modified next-auth session in app router(next.js13-14)?
With Next.js 14 app router structure, I am modifying my session inside [...nextAuth].ts middleware with basic JWT and Session callbacks.
When I get session with useSession callback in client side it is working correctly however, because my layout is server side rendered thanks to app router; when I get session with getServerSession(), it returns me only name and email which is not modified version.
How to fix this?
[..nextAuth] route.ts
export const authOptions: NextAuthCustomOptions = {
  debug: false,
  pages: {
    error: "/auth/error",
  },
  site: process.env.NEXTAUTH_URL,
  providers: [
    KeycloakProvider({
      clientId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_KEYCLOAK_ID || "",
      clientSecret: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_SECRET || "",
      issuer: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_KEYCLOAK_ISSUER || "",
    }),
  ],
  secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
  callbacks: {
    async session({ session, token }: ISessionCallbak) {
      session.accessToken = token.accessToken;
      session.expiresAt = token.expiresAt;
      session.refreshTokenExpiresIn = token.refreshTokenExpiresIn;
      session.refreshToken = token.refreshToken;
      session.tokenType = token.tokenType;
      session.registrationStep = token.registrationStep;
      return session;
    },

    async jwt({ token, user, account, profile }: IJwtCallback) {
      if (user) {
        token.id = user.id;
      }
...

layout.tsx
export default async function RootLayout({
  children,
}: Readonly<{
  children: React.ReactNode;
}>) {
  const session = await getServerSession(); //returns not modified session

I noticed that useSession (client side) session is modified successfully. But with getServerSession() it gives me default name and email data only.
